# difference between instance vs object during class instantiation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

can some one please share their knowledge on instance vs object, i am using python 2.7 version.

1. i created a class and assigned to a variable t

   ```
   class test():
       pass

   t=test()
   ```

   at this point i thought t is an object of class test
   but when i print i get a instance

   ```
   print t
   <__main__.test instance at 0x7fb1a3562b00>

   type(t)
   <type 'instance'>
   ```
2. now i created another class with object

   ```
   class Spam(object): 
       pass

   s=Spam()
   ```

   so when i printed this i was expecting it to be an object or instance , 
   but i get a class type.

   ```
   print s
   <__main__.Spam object at 0x7fb1a3560f10>
   >>> type(s)
   <class '__main__.Spam'>
   ```

i thought object is the base class from which all the classes are derived, if i mention in the class def or not. i am confused.

please share your thoughts

thanks 
pradeep

Comment: What you are seeing is the difference between old-style and new-style classes. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873/8316315) for more details.

Comment: An object is very generically *anything* that you can do `.something` on. `test` is an object (yes, it's a `class`, it's a *class object*), `'str'` is an object, *everything* is an object. An *instance* is specifically an object constructed from a class.

Comment: Do yourself a favour: Use Python 3. The object model changed a bit in between, which makes a few things clearer, among other improvements and new features.

Comment: thanks all for the feedback. i will update to python 3 and look at the link provided.